# Jenkins on docker can't reach minikube

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I'm running Jenkins with Docker.

I want to deploy Kubernetes resources from Jenkins on Minikube.

I'm facing an error that Jenkins cannot reach Minikube.

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://127.0.0.1:62756/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:62756: connect: connection refused
```

I tried to publish the Minikube's port but still having the same error.

this is the command am using:

```
 docker run \
  --name jenkins-blueocean \
  --rm \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --publish 62756:62756 \
  --volume /Users/myuser/.kube:/var/jenkins_home/.kube \
  --volume /Users/myuser/.minikube:/Users/myuser/.minikube \
  --volume /Users/myuser/.minikube/profiles:/Users/myuser/.minikube/profiles \
  --volume /Users/myuser/.minikube/profiles/minikube:/Users/myuser/.minikube/profiles/minikube \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  myjenkins-blueocean:1.1
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Thomas operating system is macos

Answer (score 0):

Minikube and docker each use separate virtual machines on macos.

You can determine the ip of the minikube machine using `minikube ip` and use that as kubernetes API server IP.

Comment: Can you explain better how to use it as kubernetes api server ip?

Comment: You are running jenkins in docker on macos, for docker a VM is used. Minikube provides a single node kubernetes cluster that is launched inside a VM, too. To talk from jenkins to minikube use the IP of the minikube VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a deployment, you need to expose the pod in order to access the resources in it from outside of your internal network.

By default, the Pod is only accessible by its internal IP address within the Kubernetes cluster. To make the container accessible from outside the Kubernetes virtual network, you have to expose the Pod as a Kubernetes Service.

The idea of a Service is to group a set of Pod endpoints into a single resource. You can configure various ways to access the grouping. By default, you get a stable cluster IP address that clients inside the cluster can use to contact Pods in the Service. A client sends a request to the stable IP address, and the request is routed to one of the Pods in the Service.

There are five types of Services:

- ClusterIP (default)
- NodePort
- LoadBalancer
- ExternalName
- Headless

More information about kubernetes services [in this link.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

To expose your service using load balancer flag, use the kubectl expose command:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

The --type=LoadBalancer flag indicates that you want to expose your Service outside of the cluster.

If you want to take a look at the complete tutorial, [follow this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service)

More information about Using a Service to [Expose Your App here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)

If you want to know more about Kubernetes API Server please [follow this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)

And [follow this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) if you want to Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API